# Unittesing AngularJS with Jasmine $location.path

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Hey I began to test our AngularJS application but I have my problems because I didnt write the code and am new in testing

so this is the code i want to test

```
//controller for all partials
app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$location) {
    $scope.go = function (path) { 
        $location.path();
    };
});
```

alle examples on the internet define a path in the brackets. cant i test this unit without defining ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: Either you copied your code and edited it in a wrong way, or it's just a non working example. `$location.path()` doesn't do anything just return path of current url when called without any parameter. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location